# Помогите написать регулярное выражение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста написать регулярное выражение.

Из строки доставать:
45 - чиста;
45а - числа с буквой;
45/2 - дробные числа;
45+ - числа с плюсиком;
45- - числа с минусом;
45-50 - числа через тире;
45 кодовая фраза - числа с кодовой фразой.

То есть, строка:

```
65 бла 65/2 бла бла 65а 65+ 65- ччч..чч 65-70 65 кодовая фраза"
```

после преобразования `str.match(/re/g)` должна превратиться в массив:

```
["65", "65/2", "65а", "65+", "65-", "65-70", "65 кодовая фраза"]
```

Все до чего пока дошел:  `/[0-9]+[\[\w\]]?/g`, достает числа и числа с буквой.
Но когда начинаю пытаться вставить вложенные квадратные скобочки, получаю ошибку синтаксиса.

Никак не пойму принципа.

Comment: А разбить по пробелах?

Comment: @entithat ну если использовать str.match то получается неважно по чему разбивать - в массив кладутся подстроки, которые подходят под регулярку. а что не подходит по тому и разбивка получается. Ну это если с флагом g.

Comment: `.match(/\d+(\/\d+|[а-я]+|\+|\-(\d+)?|\sкодовая фраза)?/g)`

Comment: именно так как ты описал: сначала число потом могут идти либо бродь ли плюс/минус, тире, кодовая фраза

Comment: Буквы только маленькие и только русские? Пробелы это только пробелы или любые пробельные символы `\s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для фразы с мусором между искомыми значениями.

1. Выделяем число длиной 1 цифра и больше ([квантификатор "x+"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers))
2. Выделяем один символ, который может быть:`/-+` или символом алфавита (кириллица, латинский), добавляем условия, что символ не обязателен ([квантификатор "x?"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers))
3. Выделяем число длиной 1 цифра и больше с условием необязательности.
4. Или выделяем `кодовая фраза`, добавляем условие необязательности.
5. Указываем параметры `igm` - [регистронезависимость, глобальный поиск и мультистроковость](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Syntax)
6. Везде используем незахватывающие скобки [(?:x)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references)

Ниже три варианта:

**1. Если пробел является обязательным признаком-разделителем.**

```js
const str = `65 бла 65/2 бла бла 65а 33 кодовая
фраза
65+ 65- ччч..чч 65-70 65 кодовая фраза
 77_ 123_99 43 _ кодовая 
фраза $$$ 55&&45$$ #85* 77 \"кодовая фраза\" 22-33 кодовая фраза
100500 \кодовая фраза\ `;

const res = str.match(/(?:^|(?<=\s))(?:\d+(?:[\/\-\+\a-zа-яё]?(?:\d+)?|\s+кодовая\s+фраза)?)(?=\s|$)/igm);
console.log(res);
```

**2. Если пробел не является обязательным признаком-разделителем.**

```js
const str = `65 бла 65/2 бла бла 65а 33 кодовая
фраза
65+ 65- ччч..чч 65-70 65 кодовая фраза
 77_ 123_99 43 _ кодовая 
фраза $$$ 55&&45$$ #85* 77 \"кодовая фраза\" 22-33 кодовая фраза
100500 \кодовая фраза\ `;

const res = str.match(/\d+(?:[\/\-\+\a-zа-яё]?(?:\d+)?|\s+кодовая\s+фраза)?/igm);
console.log(res);
```

**3. Если нет мусора.**

Можно разбить по пробелам c использованием квантификатора [x(?=y)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers)

```js
const str = "65 65/2 65а 65+ 65- 65-70 65 кодовая фраза";
const res = str.split(/\s(?=[^a-zа-яё])/ig);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: воу, круто! но вы используете сплит. а мне нужен несколько другой эффект. я хочу использовать match т.к. между нужными мне подстроками может быть куча всякого мусора. под ваш метод я перефразировал бы вопрос так: как мне разбить строку по числу или числу-с-буквой или числу--дробью или числу с плюсиком...?

Comment: Добавил вариант с мусором.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var s = `Помогите пожалуйста написать регулярное выражение.

Из строки доставать:
45 - чиста;
45а - числа с буквой;
45/2 - дробные числа;
45+ - числа с плюсиком;
45- - числа с минусом;
45-50 - числа через тире;
45 кодовая фраза - числа с кодовой фразой.

т.е. строка "65 бла 65/2 бла бла 65а 65+ 65- ччч..чч 65-70 65 кодовая фраза"
после преобразования str.match(/re/g) должна превратиться в массив
["65", "65/2", "65а", "65+", "65-", "65-70", "65 кодовая фраза"]

все до чего пока дошел - /[0-9]+[[\w]]?/g
достает числа и числа с буквой.
но когда начинаю пытаться вставить вложенные квадратные скобочки, получаю ошибку синтаксиса.
никак не пойму принципа.`

console.log(s.match(/\d+([a-zа-яёA-ZА-ЯЁ](?![a-zа-яёA-ZА-ЯЁ\d])|-\d+|[-+]|\/\d+|\s+кодовая фраза)?/g))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: куда-то пропала первая `45`

Comment: @Grundy, исправил. И про букву после числа - тоже.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const regex = /\b\d+(?:\S+|\sкодовая фраза)?/gm;
const str = `45 - чиста;
45а - числа с буквой;
45/2 - дробные числа;
45+ - числа с плюсиком;
45- - числа с минусом;
45-50 - числа через тире;
45 кодовая фраза - числа с кодовой фразой.
21
3123/422fddf кодовая фраза
22 кодовая фраза
`;

console.log(str.match(regex));
```

---

```
\b\d+(?:\S+|\sкодовая фраза)?
```

`\b` - граница слова
`\d+` - одна и более цифр
`(?:` - начало не захватываемой группы
`\S+` - один и более не пробельных символов, эквивалент `[^\r\n\t\f\v ]`
`|` - в группе означает или
`\sкодовая фраза)` - пробельный символ и кодовая фраза

Answer (score 2):

Вот так вот (используются маленькие буквы на английском и русском (удалите английские, если не нужны; добавьте флаг `i`, если большие также нужны), используются именно пробелы, а не любые пробельные символы `\s`):

```
(?:\d+[a-zа-яё+-]|\d+[/—]\d+|\d+ кодовая фраза|\d+)
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5acka

> **45** - чиста;
>
> **45а** - числа с буквой;
>
> **45/2** - дробные числа;
>
> **45+** - числа с плюсиком;
>
> **45-** - числа с минусом;
>
> **45—50** - числа через тире;
>
> **45 кодовая фраза** - числа с кодовой фразой.
>
> **65** бла **65/2** бла бла **65а** **65+** **65-** ччч..чч **65—70** **65 кодовая фраза**"